# Django, nose and selenium .. the initial state error

Tags: django, selenium, nose, django-testing, django-nose

I have installed everything for Django 1.3.1 : `django-nose` , `django-nose-selenium` , and set the test-runner as well:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

**First** it seems that by running the command: `$./manage.py test`, Django's internal test starts to run instead of Nose.

Second, by running `$nosetests` I get this :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:383: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin selenium = noseselenium.plugins:SeleniumPlugin: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
  RuntimeWarning)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:383: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin djangoliveserver = noseselenium.plugins:DjangoLiveServerPlugin: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
  RuntimeWarning)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:383: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin cherrypyliveserver = noseselenium.plugins:CherryPyLiveServerPlugin: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
  RuntimeWarning)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:383: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin selenium_fixtures = noseselenium.plugins:SeleniumFixturesPlugin: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Any Idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you add 'django_nose' to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Hi ... Thanks for your reply ... Yes, I did, and managed to solved the problem after a while ...